# How can i merge rows according to column name

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, row

I want "an b column value" add to "other b column value" which are same "a" column values

for python ↓↓↓

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| title1 | 15 |
| title2 | 12 |
| title2 | 18 |
| title3 | 8 |
| title3 | 13 |
| title4 | 7 |

I have this dataframe ↑

How can i transform to this one ↓

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| title1 | 15 |
| title2 | 30 |
| title3 | 21 |
| title4 | 7 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

Pandas has this built in functionality by combining groupby and sum together, for example

```
df.groupby("Column A").sum()
```